# Facebook SDK update - Cached access token issue

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read several post about this issue but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Basically I had the Facebook SDK "3.1.1" for iOS, and I updated the code to version "3.5.3".

I used the following code for using cached access token:

After login:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:FBAccessTokenKey];
[defaults setObject:expirationDate forKey:FBExpirationDateKey];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And next time I used the data I saved before:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
id accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:FBAccessTokenKey];
id expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:FBExpirationDateKey];
if (accessToken && expirationDate) {
    facebook.accessToken = accessToken;
    facebook.expirationDate = expirationDate;
}

[[FBSession activeSession] isOpen];
```

But now I can't use the same code, because the new SDK uses FBAccessTokenData, so I have this new code for getting the old session:

```
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    id accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:FBAccessTokenKey];
    id expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:FBExpirationDateKey];

  if (accessToken && expirationDate) {
    FBAccessTokenData* accessTokenData = [FBAccessTokenData createTokenFromString:accessToken permissions:nil expirationDate:expirationDate loginType:FBSessionLoginTypeFacebookApplication refreshDate:nil];
    // add the old token to the cache
    [FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy.defaultInstance cacheFBAccessTokenData:accessTokenData];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:FBAccessTokenKey];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:FBExpirationDateKey];
    [defaults synchronize];
  }

  // to login explicitly
  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[ @"email", @"user_location", @"user_birthday" ] allowLoginUI:NO completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
    [self session:session updatedState:state withError:error];
}];
```

And Im here because this last code is not working, I tried using nil instead of passing permissions and I get the same result, I have to login again and get a new token.
But I just want to obtain the old session and not show the login popup again for the users.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Regards

Comment: I found that the problems is related to the permissions. The thing is that I don't really know exactly about the old permissions because this code is used on several apps.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

You are requesting for the special permission `user_birthday`, if you do this without having your facebook app reviewed by facebook you will not receive this information and (on purpose or not) your session won't be cached.
It means your activeSession will be `FBSessionStateCreated`instead of `FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded`.

Note that if you are testing on a facebook account that is also Administrator or Developer of the facebook app it should work without any problems, because you'll get the "user_birthday" despite your app doesn't being reviewed by facebook.

To solve this problem you can either remove the need for `user_birthday` OR get your app reviewed by facebook. If you are going to the first solution don't forget to unauthorize your app from facebook.